# DevC++ and wxWidgets

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

I am trying to use WxWidgets with DevC++.  I used the Tools|Package Manager to install wxWidgets.  I verified the installation with no errors.  When I try to compile any of the example projects, I get errors indicating that the wxWidget include files are not found.
The include files are in the DevC++ folder.  I tried copying them to the DevC++/include folder, but that didn't help.  Any suggestion would be appreciated.  I am just getting back into C++ programming after a hiatus of 10 or more years